# Adding scroll by mouse grab for multiple elements, javascript

Tags: javascript

EDIT: I HAVE SOLVED IT, THANK YOU FOR READING.

The issue was that my variables: isDown, startX, scrollleft were declared with 'let' and that they were inside the onload() function. I moved the variables outside of the function and it works.

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

I am have a div that scrolls horizontally. For aesthetic purposes, I have removed the scrollbar and want people to scroll it by grabbing with mouse. I copied the below code:

```
const slider = document.querySelector(".scroll");
let isDown = false;
let startX;
let scrollLeft;

slider.addEventListener("mousedown", e => {
  isDown = true;
  slider.classList.add("active");
  startX = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
  scrollLeft = slider.scrollLeft;
});
slider.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
  isDown = false;
  slider.classList.remove("active");
});
slider.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
  isDown = false;
  slider.classList.remove("active");
});
slider.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
  if (!isDown) return;
  e.preventDefault();
  const x = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
  const walk = x - startX;
  slider.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - walk;
});
```

**My question is** how do I add this to multiple elements? I have a total of four different boxes of the same design, all of which I want to scroll by grabbing. I can do this by copy-pasting the above code four times, however that is not ideal. I tried to do modificatons like below:

```
// basically code on top with modifications

    let isDown = false;
    let startX;
    let scrollLeft;
    
    let myList = document.getElementsByClassName('scroll') // four elements in this collection
    
    for (let y = 0; y < myList.length; y++) {
    
        // bascially all the addeventlisteners as on top, but I change the
        // 'slider' to myList[y] instead.
    
    }
```

I am not sure why it doesn't work. I tested adding console.log(myList[y]) to each event listener and they were able to log the correct elements on all the events. However they just won't scroll.

How may I add scroll to all four of my elements without copy-pasting the code four times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change for loop to foreach
try this

```js
let myList = document.querySelectorAll('.scroll')


let isDown = [];
let startX = [];
let scrollLeft = [];

myList.forEach((slider,i)=> {
  slider.addEventListener("mousedown", e => {
    isDown[i] = true;
    slider.classList.add("active");
    startX[i] = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
    scrollLeft[i] = slider.scrollLeft;
  });
  slider.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
    isDown[i] = false;
    slider.classList.remove("active");
  });
  slider.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
    isDown[i] = false;
    slider.classList.remove("active");
  });
  slider.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
    if (!isDown[i]) return;
    e.preventDefault();
    const x = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
    const walk = x - startX[i];
    slider.scrollLeft = scrollLeft[i] - walk;
  });
})
```